# AudioClip issue in unity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, audio, virtual-reality

I wrote script to play sound when player destroy cube.

```
{

public GameObject blastEffect;
public float offSet;
public int amountOfDestroyed = 0;

private AudioSource source;
public AudioClip clip;

private void Start()
{
    source = GetComponent<AudioSource>();
}


private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
{
    if (collision.gameObject.tag == "Bullet")
    {
        source.PlayOneShot(clip);
        GameManager.instance.score += 1;
        Vector3 spawnPosition = new Vector3(transform.position.x, offSet, transform.position.z);
        Instantiate(blastEffect, transform.position, blastEffect.transform.rotation);        
        Destroy(gameObject); 
    }
}
}
```

And the sound does not start even tho the cube is destroyed

[image]

I also tried this way

```
{
public GameObject blastEffect;
public float offSet;
public int amountOfDestroyed = 0;

public AudioSource blastSound;


private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
{
    if (collision.gameObject.tag == "Bullet")
    {
        blastSound.Play();
        GameManager.instance.score += 1;
        Vector3 spawnPosition = new Vector3(transform.position.x, offSet, transform.position.z);
        Instantiate(blastEffect, transform.position, blastEffect.transform.rotation);        
        Destroy(gameObject); 
    }
}
}
```

But then when I wanted to add this sound to prefab on which this script was, I got information "TypMissMatch" and also the cube has not disappeared idk why. (Cubes spawn at the start of the round.)

[image]

Comment: probably doesnt play because you destroyed the ovbject trying to make the sound

Comment: But I play the sound before it get destroyed, as well I Instantiate Blast Effect which works fine.

Comment: no, you start the play process, you make your blast and then you kill the object.. try destroy(gameobject,5); for example to destroy in 5s see if your sound comes then

Comment: Thank you sir, I thought wrong about it.

Answer (score 0):

So I changed the first version of my script like this:

```
{
public GameObject blastEffect;
public float offSet;
public int amountOfDestroyed = 0;


public AudioClip clip;

private void Start()
{
    GameManager.instance.source = GetComponent<AudioSource>();
}
private void OnCollisionEnter(Collision collision)
{
    if (collision.gameObject.tag == "Bullet")
    {
        GameManager.instance.source.PlayOneShot(clip);
        GameManager.instance.score += 1;
        Vector3 spawnPosition = new Vector3(transform.position.x, offSet, transform.position.z);
        Instantiate(blastEffect, transform.position, blastEffect.transform.rotation);        
        Destroy(gameObject); 
    }
}
```

}

And added this verse to my game manger which is singleton

```
public AudioSource source;
```

I did this that way because now this audio is audible even after cube is destroyed.